# Exoplayer load frame when seekbar change

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using Exoplayer to play a locally saved video.

I noticed that when you move the seekbar the video changes only when it is released.
Is there a way to load the video frame with every move of the seekbar?

Comment: You can create a custom SeekBar. Create a timer that will be active when the video is playing. For instance, when you start playing the video, start the timer and update the SeekBar every 200 ms. Also if you manually Seek the video, just call player.seekTo(millis) and it will load the frames according to the SeekBar value.

Comment: Thanks I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thumbnails you see when you seek a video timeline are actually usually contained in a separate media stream or 'track'.

This is created on the server side and delivered as part of the streamed video, or in your case the locally saved video file, as a track in the video container.

The client downloads (or uploads from s saved file) this track and when a user seeks, it displays the thumbnail image that is closest to the time the user is seeking to.

Generating the thumbnails on the fly is possible but it does require the video to be loaded, decoded and a frame displayed at the point the user was seeking to.

This is quite a bit of work to do in the time available so is not usually a  practical approach.

Comment: Thanks. Have you an example how to generate thumbnail on the fly? My video it 10 sec long.

Comment: You can see some discussion here - I am really not sure if generating it on the fly is going to give you what you are looking for: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5519